# Voices missing from VLC audio output

Tags: sound, vlc

I have a problem with VLC player in Ubuntu 14.04.

When a movie is playing, it has sound effects in the background, but no voices/dialogue.

I heard I should change VLC sound to stereo mode but it's locked.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please specify, what means "locked" for you? It really looks like problem with "Home Theater" speakers or something like that.

Comment: I mean it's gray and I can't click on it

Comment: Do you have multiple speakers or just stereo?

Comment: I have regular speakers on my laptop

Comment: I saw that. It maybe your sound setttings are just 2-channel output. Open alsamixer in terminal window or install pavucontrol to see if you can find a suitable setting for your card.